# Problem in SQLite3 installation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, installation, sqlite

The following error comes up:

```
C:\gem>gem install sqlite3-ruby --local
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing sqlite3-ruby:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

C:/Ruby/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for #include <sqlite3.h>
... no
sqlite3.h is missing. Install SQLite3 from http://www.sqlite.org/ first.
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=C:/Ruby/bin/ruby
        --with-sqlite3-dir
        --without-sqlite3-dir
        --with-sqlite3-include
        --without-sqlite3-include=${sqlite3-dir}/include
        --with-sqlite3-lib
        --without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/lib


Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/sqlite3-ruby-1
.3.0 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/sqlite3-ruby-1.3.0/ext/sqlite3/
gem_make.out
```

I have copied all the necessary files required in the Ruby/Bin folder, still it keeps reporting this error that sqlite3.h is missing.

Please do tell where do I have to place sqlite3.h, when I am installing the gem locally as you can see and I am currently using 1.3.0 version of SQLite3 for its installation.
I have tried with the solutions that were posted for similar problems. And I am using Windows XP.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Stupid question, and you may actually have answered it without me noticing - but have you actually installed the sqlite3 executable, as gem suggests?

Comment: I have actually copied the executable sqlite3.exe, the .dll file along with some other necessary files in Ruby/Bin folder that was all I did, I didn't go through any installation process as such..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this problem. This is the solution I found. It's not very pretty, but it worked for me. In my case, I was using cygwin. There's probably a similar way to do it without using cygwin, but I don't know how.

1) Download the *source* of SQLite. I went for SQLite 3.6.23, somewhat arbitrarily, via this URL: 
http://www.sqlite.org/src/info/4ae453ea7b
If that doesn't work, then go to the release timeline at http://www.sqlite.org/src/timeline?n=200&t=release&y=ci , choose a release, and download the ZIP file of it.

2) Unpack the ZIP archive somewhere. Go to that directory in cygwin. Execute these commands:

> ./configure
>   make
>   make sqlite3.dll
>   make install

3) Copy the sqlite3.exe and sqlite3.dll from the directory where `make` created them into somewhere on your path.

4) Once that's done, `gem install sqlite3-ruby` finally worked.

I was following this guide: http://blade.nagaokaut.ac.jp/cgi-bin/scat.rb/ruby/ruby-talk/240902

Comment: Thanks it worked, but I had already shifted to Ubuntu and I didn't encountered any problem there, but it will be helpful for others..

Answer (score 2):

I know this has been closed for a while but I was having the same issue and this
helped. Install apt-cyg. First install subversion and wget through the standard
cygwin setup program. Then run the following commands:

```
wget rawgit.com/transcode-open/apt-cyg/master/apt-cyg
install apt-cyg /bin
```

Now using apt-cyg install the sqlite3 development:

```
apt-cyg install libsqlite3-devel
```

and finally

```
$ gem install sqlite3-ruby
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Fetching: sqlite3-ruby-1.3.3.gem (100%)

#######################################################

Hello! The sqlite3-ruby gem has changed it's name to just sqlite3.  Rather than
installing `sqlite3-ruby`, you should install `sqlite3`.  Please update your
dependencies accordingly.

Thanks from the Ruby sqlite3 team!

<3 <3 <3 <3

#######################################################

Successfully installed sqlite3-1.3.6
Successfully installed sqlite3-ruby-1.3.3
2 gems installed
Installing ri documentation for sqlite3-1.3.6...
Installing ri documentation for sqlite3-ruby-1.3.3...
Installing RDoc documentation for sqlite3-1.3.6...
Installing RDoc documentation for sqlite3-ruby-1.3.3...
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by following these suggestions: http://www.skorks.com/2009/08/installing-and-using-sqlite-with-ruby-on-windows/

Basically you can download from sqlite.org, the DLL and shell file and make sure you copy the DLL in each of the ruby versions you have installed, in their `/bin` directory. You can place the shell file somewhere in your system path, I have a folder `c:\bin`. Then you can install `pik gem install sqlite3`

Answer (score -1):

replace with sqlite3 (1.3.10-x64-mingw32) in Gemfile.lock worked for me.